# Why are trophies awarded when the tournament gets cancelled?

Tags: basketball, tournaments, collegiate

On the day each NCAA basketball conference tournament was cancelled, (both for men and women), there was a small ceremony where one team won the trophy for their respective conference.  I am assuming that they awarded it to the highest remaining ranking team.

Why is this OK?  Shouldn't it have been better to not have awarded trophies at all?  Shouldn't they also apply this logic to March Madness and arbitrarily pick a winner?

Comment: VTC as opinion-based. A lot of people don't think it's okay to award any trophy before the end of the competition, and a lot of people think it would not be okay to not award any trophy at all. You have to pick one of those things - the organisers chose one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIRC when the ACC cancelled their tournament, the NCAA had not yet cancelled theirs. So the ACC simply designated their regular season champion (Florida State) as their NCAA tournament qualifier as ACC Champion. The NCAA cancelled their tournament afterwards.